# Reading a particular set from a file in python

Tags: python

I want read from file and store it as an array, for example :

test.txt :

```
 1,2,7,2,3
 5,8,1,6
 7,4
 7,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,5,4
```

Output:

```
 {1,2,3,7}
 {1,5,6,8}
 {4,7}
 {0,4,5,7}
```

How to fetch it as an array?

Comment: I want to read this as an array to perform some calculation

Comment: {1,2} is  a set not a list first of all you mean you want to load each line and load it as frozen set?

Comment: yes i want to use the set

Comment: did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to parse your file in order to output the sets of numbers for each line, isn't it ?

If it is, a solution could be:

```py
with open("test.txt") as f:
    content = f.read()
l = [set(int(x) for x in l.split(','))
        for l in content.splitlines()]
print (l)
```

This piece of code does not sort the set though, to do this, you will have to use `frozenset` as well as the `sorted` built-in function.

Comment: How to iterate in a set?

Comment: Reading [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

- Read from file
- Split using newline character
- Replace `,` in set

Like this

```
with open("test.txt",'r') as text_file: #reading in read mode
   #to get the list of lines replacing new line
   lines=text_file.read().split('\n')

   #replace commas and make a set
   set_of_lines = [ set(line.replace(",","")) for line in lines] 

for line in set_of_lines:
    print(line)
```